# Run Here Maps embedded in Nokia X app

Tags: here-api, nokiax

How can we run Here Maps embedded in an Android app specifically for Nokia X? We would like the app route to a location we will define from the current location.

In Google Maps we did it as follows.

```
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?   saddr="+myLocation.latitude+","+myLocation.longitude+"&daddr="+latLng.longitude+","+latLng.latitude));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER );    
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Thanks

Comment: https://api.maps.nokia.com/en/apireference/2.2.0/symbols/nokia.maps.geo.PixelProjection.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HERE maps also supports google.navigation and geo schemes. If you want to navigate somewhere, you can use google.navigation scheme:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d google.navigation:q=Vuores
```

If you just want to show a location on map, use geo scheme

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d geo:61.437424,23.81297
```

Comment: Thanks but due to Nokia X limitations I need to do this with Here Maps.

Comment: did you check what was suggested. There is only HERE maps in Nokia X, and riksa says its supports the same format as google, so if that is still lagging something, then please specify in details.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Jukka. I misunderstood riksa's comment. I will give it a try. Thanks riksa.